# Different views for landscape and portrait - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, layout

I making a project in which i need to have one view for horizontal and the other one for vertical orientation. Also i need to have a collection view in the horizontal view and table view for my vertical view.

I have been trying to found some tutorials, but without success or the solution was to old. I am using Xcode 6.

Comment: This is really easy with iOS8 storyboards and size classes.  You can easily select which items are installed in the different size classes.   Have a look at the WWDC session from last year on Interface Builder and building adaptive apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can implement the equivalent of a table view using a collection view. A collection view is basically a table view on steroids: more powerful, more configurable, more generic. Rather than try to implement two types of views and switch between them, a design which fits the Apple pattern would contain just a collection view, which in landscape mode displays the items in two or three columns, but in portrait mode displays just a single column.

[This article](http://damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout) describes how to implement custom layouts for collection views, and it contains links to other hopefully relevant material.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is switch from collection view to table view, then do what @BrettDonald said. But if you need a more generic way to switch views, implement this in your view controller:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.dynamicView removeFromSuperView];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.dynamicView = [[LandscapeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    } else {
        self.dynamicView = [[PortraitView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.dynamicView];
}
```

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is actually deprecated in iOS 8, so you'll need to run the same code in the suggested `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` also.